# UDP Port Cannot Receive Data

Tags: c#, udp

I'm trying to receive and send data by UDP port. it works with TCP very good but as when as I change it to UDP, it corrupts.

here is my UDP code just for receive:

```
Socket receiver_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.11.254"), 11000);
.
.
.
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    receiver_socket.Connect(ipep);         
}

private void Receive_socket_delegate()
{
    receiver_socket.BeginReceive(r_buff, 0, r_buff.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socket_receive_data), receiver_socket);
}

void socket_receive_data(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
    int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
    if (recv > 0)
    {...
    }
}
```

What is the wrong?

Comment: You don't need to connect with the method in UDP. What is your problem please explain detailed.

Comment: There is a terrible problem with TCP ports that forced me to use UDP instead. in the TCP case, if your data is more than packet capacity, it will send data nonstop so there will be some incorrect data among them. however, this problem is not in the UDP. I mean if some data is more than packet capacity, it will ignore extra data. therfore I wanna use it

Comment: Is it solution for you?

Comment: _"There is a terrible problem with TCP ports"_ -- no, there's not. _"there will be some incorrect data"_ -- no, there won't be. You need to accept the fact that if you got incorrect data while using TCP, the bug is in _your_ code, not in TCP. As for your question, it's not possible to answer without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Even with one, the most likely answer is that you have a network configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is unbound protocol, you don't need **receiver_socket.Connect();**. Also there is **UDPClient** object for UDP communication.

```
UdpClient listener = new Udpclient();
//Socket receiver_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.11.254"), 11000);
.
.
.
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    //receiver_socket.Connect(ipep);
    Thread listeningthread = new Thread(Receive_socket_delegate);
    listeningthread.Start();         
}

private void Receive_socket_delegate()
{
   // receiver_socket.BeginReceive(r_buff, 0, r_buff.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socket_receive_data), receiver_socket);
    while(true)
    {
    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref ipep);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state=>{
    socket_receive_data(bytes);
    });
    }
}

void socket_receive_data(byte[] bytes)
{
    // Write or use your data in here "bytes"
    if (recv > 0)
    {...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gets error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: You must call the Bind method before performing this operation